# Is calling str.split("a string") better than calling "a string".split()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to cut a string in two and I'm doing this.

```
parts = str.split("street one")
```

Would it be better to do this? Or more efficient?

```
parts = "street one".split()
```

Comment: Second one is correct

Comment: the only time i regularly use the first style is with `str.maketrans()` for python 3

Comment: (It doesn't matter at all. Look at how the code you're working in does it and just be consistent.)

Comment: @JETM I've read the answer and yes, possibly it's something very similar to my question. I'm going to try to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Given an object `obj` of type `Class`, the following two notations are equivalent:

```
obj.method(arg)
Class.method(obj, arg)
```

So in your case, these two are equivalent:

```
"street one".split()
str.split("street one")
```

And these two are equivalent:

```
"street one".split(" ")
str.split("street one", " ")
```

Comment: using `%timeit`, the two seem to be almost identical from an efficiency standpoint as well

Comment: But, If the definition of the function is `str.split(self, separator, maxsplit):` .If you use the first way `str.split("street one")`The string that you pass to the function is passed as self? On second thought, I think the second way is better.

Comment: The string will be captured as the `self` parameter in *all* cases, even when calling `"street one".split()`.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid, and correct, Python. So the question is simply which is stylistically preferable and more "Pythonic". I would say that the second is Pythonic and should be preferred; but the first is not "wrong".

I am not aware of any performance differences between the two forms.

Comment: But, If the definition of the function is `str.split(self, separator, maxsplit):` .If you use the first way `str.split("street one")` The string that you pass to the function is passed as self? On second thought, I think the second way is better.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them perform the same task of splitting.i.e-> ['street','one'].
Anyway you do it, it's pretty much the same